# Wpf how to shrink page in frame?

Tags: c#, wpf

I researched on the form and there are already solutions but none of them worked for me. Belove screenshot to visualise the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Main.xaml

```
 <Frame x:Name="Main" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="95,86,0,10" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

#### Account.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="Project.WPF.UI.Pages.Account"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.WPF.UI.Pages"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Height="auto" Width="auto"
  Title="Account">

<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gridTop" Margin="0,0,0,500">

        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="EDIT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="706,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="46" Width="84"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnDeleteAccount" Content="DELETE ACCOUNT" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="46" Width="167" Margin="400,0,0,0" />
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="SAVE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="599,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="46" Width="84"/>
    </Grid>
    
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain" Margin="0,105,0,0">
        <Label x:Name="lblUserName" Content="User Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSurname" Content="Surname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblMembershipType" Content="Membership Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblUserType" Content="UserType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblEmail" Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblAddress1" Content="Address 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblAddress2" Content="Address 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,269,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblAddress3" Content="Address 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,303,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblCity" Content="City" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,337,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblState" Content="State" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,371,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblCountry" Content="Country" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,405,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblPostalCode" Content="PostalCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,439,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

#### Main.xaml.cs

```
    private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.NavigationService.Navigate(new Account());
    }
```

How can a fit the account page in the frame? Even though window is maximised or resized, the account page will be fit in frame.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why have you got a huge margin on the page's grid? You should never do this: Margin="0,0,0,500">

Comment: maybe you can configure the outter and inner grids with your custom rowDefinitions and ColumnDefinition instead of using margins. That would help you. You can also set the background of each grid to see what is its real position on the window. Finally, the content of the Account.xaml will adapt to the previous size of the frame, not the other way round; if Account.xaml is bigger it won't fit in your frame.

Comment: If you want to use this fixed-size Account.xaml but make it shrink when placed in your frame, you can set a viewbox inside your frame and inside the viewbox, your Account grid. This will reduce also the fontsize of your texts and your row and columns sizes proportionally. But for sure, there must be more elegant ways to achive what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you change Account.xaml on this way then it will be handeled the problem.

```
 <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnDeleteAccount" Content="DELETE ACCOUNT"   Height="46" Width="167"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="SAVE"  Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="46" Width="84"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnEdit"  Content="EDIT" Height="46" Width="84"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="lblUserName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="User Name" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Name" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblSurname" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Surname" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblMembershipType" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Membership Type" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblUserType" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"  Content="UserType" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblEmail" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Email"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblAddress1" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Address 1"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblAddress2" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Address 2" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblAddress3" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Address 3"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblCity" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0"  Content="City"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblState" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0"  Content="State"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblCountry" Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Country"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblPostalCode" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0"  Content="PostalCode"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Roboto Slab"/>
    
    <TextBox x:Name="txtUserName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320"  FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320" FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtSurName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320"  FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtMembershipType" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320" FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtUserType" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320" FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmail" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="320" FontSize="20" Background="#FFECECEC"/>
</Grid>
```